# "Although GNOME Shell integration extension is running, native host connector is not detected." error when installing GNOME Shell Extensions

Tags: gnome, firefox, gnome-shell-extension

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, trying to install GNOME Shell Extensions, GNOME Tweaks (both of which I think installed 'successfully'?) and the browser extension to the Shell extensions website, to use on Firefox/Chromium.

I have the browser shortcut installed, but I always get this message:

> Although GNOME Shell integration extension is running, native host connector is not detected. Refer documentation for instructions about installing connector.

I have been struggling for the last few days trying to install this connector. On the shell extensions page, there is no ability to toggle any of the extensions on/off.
However, through the Tweaks app, I already have a couple extensions working (always show workspaces, windows list, workspace indicator).

I have tried a few things, mainly CLI stuff, nothing works, and I'm a terribly confused n00b. Please, can somebody help me?

P.S. my Settings app is no longer found anywhere.

Does the Cmake option usually work as a last resort?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily install the connector (`chrome-gnome-shell`) from your package manager or terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install chrome-gnome-shell
```

Reference: [Wiki](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShellIntegrationForChrome/Installation)

Answer (score 0):

[GNOME Shell browser integration Installation Guide](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/GnomeShellIntegration/Installation?action=show&redirect=Projects%2FGnomeShellIntegrationForChrome%2FInstallation) says that latest releases of the *chrome-gnome-shell* connector, 10.1-5 at the time I am writing this answer, supports Firefox.

> For Firefox you should manually install extension from [Mozilla Addons](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/gnome-shell-integration/) site. Please note that Firefox is supported since connector version 8.

It also says that Opera was supported starting from the release 7 of the connector, but then the plugin was disabled on the Opera site.

> Opera was supported since connector version 7 up to version 10.1. However extension [was deactivated at Opera addons website without any technical explanation](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShellIntegration/Installation?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=opera-conversation.png).

I didn't find any explicit information about Chromium, but I expect the extension on that browser to be able to use the connector.